Tangent bundle of the 4-sphere
Let $\tau(S^4)$ denote the tangent bundle over the $S^4$ and $M_n$ be the trivial bundle over $S^4$ with fibre $\mathbb{R}^n$. In Rachel Mcenroe's paper discussing Milnor's construction of the exotic 7-sphere, the following claim is made:$\tau(S^4) \oplus M_1 \approx M_5$. Can anyone give me some insight into this?

Look at the inclusion $S^4\to R^5$ and splitting of the pull-back of the tangent bundle of $R^5$ which splits as $\tau(S^4)\oplus \nu(S^4)$, where $\nu$ is the normal bundle.
